# Проблема с скроллом на jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".arrow").click(function () {
        var elementClick = $(this).attr("href");
        var destination = $(elementClick).offset().top;
        jQuery("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({scrollTop: destination}, 800);
        return false;
    });

});//end ready
```

По клику на кнопку должно скролить на секцию ниже, но выбивает ошибку ***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined.***
Подскажите в чем ошибка

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка от того, что elementClick не определен. А не определен он потому, что ссылка по href битая.

Так-то код правильный, за исключением селектора body, html. Но до него все равно дело не доходит.

Comment: <a href="#destination" class="arrow" id="scroll"></a> Что нужно исправить?

Comment: а этот #destination есть в html? а что будет, если вставить `console.log(elementClick);`?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Просто я не указал id секции на которую нужно проскролить

Comment: ну то есть мой ответ правильный